# C# project gives SecurityException after moving to a different PC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, permissions, shared-directory

a project within my solution (.NET 4) uses a proprietary dll for communicating with some instrumentation through the Internet.
I worked on a VMware Windows 8 virtual machine, because I'm a Mac user; I set the Visual studio 2012 project directory in the VMware shared folder (so Time Machine could backup my solution). Everything worked fine.
Then I moved the solution to a Windows 7 machine. When I debug my project, everything works but the code invoking the proprietary dll. The exception is:

```
"Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed." (System.Security.SecurityException)
```

If I create a new test project (also in the same solution) from scratch and use the dll, it works as expected. I tried to paste all the old project files in the new test project, but it does not work. I think it is because the files "remember" they were born in an unsecure folder (the VMware shared folder).
I know that I could use the Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Configuration tool, but I don't know how to use it.
Could you guys give me some hints?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check the properties on the files... Sometimes when you copy files between machines, they're marked as unsafe and thus blocked... See if you can Unblock them.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see the Unblock button on my project files and folders... thanks anyway!